# how to copy a rigged leg with IK + target in the same armature?

Tags: rigging

Is there an intelligent way to copy a rigged leg with IK + target?

Tries:

- I can copy the bones + IK, but then the target (empty) won't be copied.
- i can copy the armature + target in object mode, but then i am left with two armatures (i want just one)

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you made these IK setup with empties by yourself or via the "add ik with empty"  operator? I am tempted to find someone at the BF to cry about this operator x)

Comment: Add ik with empty. Never had problems with that.

Comment: Well you don't, until you do 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key issue here is that your target are empty objects that are not part of the armature.

That's part of why it's usually better to keep using bones from within the same armature to build any kind of mechanics in a rig: it gets hard to manage otherwise. If it's possible for you, I'd advise to quickly switch your empty objects by bones.

Otherwise, I am afraid you will have to copy your bones in edit mode and then your empty objects in object mode separately and then set manually the empty targets in the new chain's constraints.

### Switch empties for bones

- select your empty in object mode
- <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> > Cursor to selected
- select your armature and go to edit mode
- <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> to add a bone at your cursor location
- Name that bone with something descriptive like "MCH_IK_Target" (MCH is a common prefix for mechanical bones).
- Optional, I like to select the tail of the bone and press <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>S</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> to move it closer to the head so to distinguish it to the other bones.
- In pose mode, select the yellow bone of the the IK chain you want to edit
- In the Bone Constraints tab, change the IK constraint's target by the Armature object, and set the bone to the one we made above:
  [image: final result]

### If this IK chain is supposed to be symmetrical

(EG it is a leg or an arm)

- make sure all the bones are on either side of +X or -X (Blender's left and right sides) in Edit Mode.
- make sure all the bones names end with `.L` or `.R` depending the side they are on. You can use the Batch Renamer via <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd> for that:
  [image: batch rename]
- select the IK chain bones in Edit Mode and use the menu Armature > Symmetrize. It will duplicate your chain, put it on the other side of X, rename it and set up the right bones in your constraints:
  [image: Symmetrized]